# Show library items to anonymous users in Office365

Tags: javascript, office-365

We have a client in Office365, they have been using the public site for a while now and we put in some javascript that pulls images from libraries and displays them in various places as rotating banners.

This has been working fine for almost a year, and in the last two weeks the client has noticed that the images haven't been displaying. We have been looking into it, and Microsoft seem to have made a change that will only allow the javascript to query the library if the users is logged in. This won't work for us as the images must be shown to anonymous users.

As anyone else had the same experience, and how did you get round the change from Microsoft?

Comment: Did you verify that anonymous permissions are on for the site and list?  http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-server-help/grant-permissions-to-anonymous-users-HA101805390.aspx ?  What was the HTTP error code you get when anonymous user tries to access the image via javascript?

Answer (score 1):

So it turns out, after real deep javascript debugging, that there was an issue that is related to webKit standards VS IE standards.

We had a find("") call in a line of code. It was set to find("z\:row") which worked in IE but not in others, while find("row") worked in all other browsers and not IE.

We effectively had to duplicate the javascript to cater for IE and non IE users. I know this is a dirty solution but it got it working across all browsers again.

Answer (score 0):

JS calls to SharePoint online is not permitted for anonymous users. As option you can grant access to anonymous user on the picture library and add XsltListViewWebPart to the page in hidden placeholder. In this case you have json on the page that contains data for a XsltListViewWebPart. This data can be retrieved and used in your JS.